# SSIS error when migrating from SQL Server to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ssis, odbc

I'm creating a simple SSIS package in Visual Studio 2019 to simulate how I'll migrate one sql table to postgres. I've been able easily to create one connection manager local the source and PostgreSQL30 for the destination and the connection test run successfully and the tables are listed properly.
When I setup the ODBC Destination Editor, I select my connection manager and I see all of my tables in Postgres, in this format: "schema"."tablename", with the double quotes there.
Now if I leave it as that and try to get to the Mappings on the left side, this error comes up. see the screenshot

[image]

The error is complaining about a column called "nam"
I don't have that column anywhere in source or destination, I do have "name" but not "nam"
Because of that error, can't click on the mapping section. Where is it getting that column?

Comment: I checked a reference package I had that used PostGres as a source. It used the double quote format to reference the schema/table e.g. "elliedb"."Loan" You might try changing the Data Access mode from Table Name to something else and see whether that makes it any better.

Comment: From SQL? Postgresql has SQL too.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean? I'm trying to migrate data that reside in another server in SQL to another server in PostgreSQL

Comment: SQL is a _language_. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis: If it is a trial to alter existing package there may still be some metadata from previous state.

Right Click on Data Flow Component -> Show Advanced Editor -> Refresh

Related: [Advanced Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/advanced-editor?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Just for trying, I awarded you the points instead of going to waste. I'll come back here when I return to work to give more feedback. thx